# Go Templates: looping over index

Tags: templates, go, range

I want to render a simple pagination list in a Go html/template. Go templates only support for loops over ranges (`{{range x}}{{.}}{{end}}`) - I only have a simple `int`. Is there a more elegant way than creating a fake slice, map, or chan of the right size? All of that seems a bit heavy handed just for outputting something N times.

Answer (score 3):

You can register a function which produces a slice:

```
package main

import (
  "os"
  "text/template"
)

func main() {

    funcMap := template.FuncMap{
      "slice": func(i int) []int { return make([]int, i) },
    }

    tmpl := `{{$x := .}}{{range slice 10}}<p>{{$x}}</p>{{end}}`
    t, _ := template.New("template").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(tmpl)
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, "42")

}
```

Check it in [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/R5-gmKpegP)

Comment: Yeah, but that still involves creating a new slice (potentially using quite a bit of memory), just to achieve a simple 1..n loop. That seems odd.